# In a pic with n args, is it possible to use the default value for only one arg?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Suppose I have a `pic` with 3 `args`: draw color, fill color and text of a node.

I set the default values as:

```
pics/mynode/.default={red}{olive}{My node}
```

so, if I write:

```
\pic {mynode};
```

TikZ uses all the default values, and if I write:

```
\pic {mynode={green}{yellow}{Another node}};
```

it uses my values.

Is it possible to write something like this:

```
\pic {mynode={pink}{cyan}{...?...}};
```

in order to make TikZ use the default value for the third `arg` and my values for the other ones?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{%
    pics/mynode/.style n args={3}{code={%
        \node[draw=#1,fill=#2] {#3};
    }},
    pics/mynode/.default={red}{olive}{My node}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic {mynode}; % This uses all the default values
    \pic at (0,-1) {mynode={green}{yellow}{Another node}};% This uses my values 
    \pic at (0,-2) {mynode={pink}{cyan}{}}; % I'd like this uses only one default values
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check whether `#3` is empty:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\ifemptyTF}[3]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax #2\else #3\fi
}

\tikzset{%
    pics/mynode/.style n args={3}{code={%
        \node[draw=#1,fill=#2] {\ifemptyTF{#3}{Default}{#3}};
    }},
    pics/mynode/.default={red}{olive}{My node}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic {mynode}; % This uses all the default values
    \pic at (0,-1) {mynode={green}{yellow}{Another node}};% This uses my values
    \pic at (0,-2) {mynode={pink}{cyan}{}}; % I'd like this uses only one default values
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]